# Ruby Time.now.to_i PHP equivalent

Tags: php, ruby, time

Any idea how can I get the same result as with Ruby in PHP? Unix epoch time.

```
timeint = Time.now.to_i
puts timeint
```

Result:

> 1443253948

I tried `http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php` but not much good result.

EDIT:

Seems this does the trick, never thought about:

```
$epoch = time();
```

Comment: which type of result you want in ruby?

Comment: I wanted the same result in PHP as the one I get in ruby, seems `time()` is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i correctly understand your question then function `time` or `strtotime` is that you looking for.

I tested on local:

ruby:

```
puts Time.now.to_i
```

result:

> 1443279728

php:

```
echo time();
echo strtotime('now');
```

result:

> 1443279759
>
> 1443279785